# Buggy punctuation after inline tags

Tags: discussion, design, browsers

In the question [What makes a good tag-wiki entry?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1007/what-makes-a-good-tag-wiki-entry) from meta.tex.sx, the input `... [tag:linguistics], ...` (*without* a space before the comma) is rendered as follows (no free-hand circles, sorry):

[image]

The comma shouldn't start the 2nd line, obviously. Can this please be fixed?

EDIT: Here's another instance where the result looks much worse in my opinion, with just ")." on the last line. For me, the question [Merge {conditional} and {ifthen}](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1216/merge-conditional-and-ifthen) renders as

[image]

Comment: how in the world is this *our* bug?

Comment: @Jeff: Honestly? I had _no idea whatsoever_ what this bug is caused by (due to lack of knowledge). From your comment and retagging I gather it could be a bug in Firefox 3.6, but I didn't think of this when posting the question.

Comment: @Jeff: OK, I don't know much about CSS, but I investigated a bit. In `.post-tag` I see both `display:inline-block;` and `white-space:nowrap;`, and Firefox 3.6 doesn't seem to like this combination. (I can't tell if Firefox _should_ like it). I gather the `inline-block` is needed for `margin:2px 2px 6px 0;` taking effect, but I think the latter could be avoided. Then one could fix the bug by just omitting `display:inline-block;`. As I say, I'm not a CSS expert, but if a major established browser like Firefox 3.6 shows this behaviour, it's worth fixing this, and yes, partly it _is_ your bug.

Answer (score 3):

I've given it +1 because it's a reasonable question to ask. However, I think it's probably quite tricky to fix; it's more of a quirk in the browser's rendering engine than something the site could do anything about.

It's also something of an edge case, dependant on the exact combination of browser/OS/font as much as it is on the text itself -- I'm not seeing it when I browse to the same URL.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Of course the actual point of the line break depends on a lot of stuff, but it would be interesting to know if the _possibility_ of a line break before the comma depends on the browser/OS/font.